# How to change edit control's blinking line cursor's color in winapi?

Tags: winapi

Is it possible to change blinking/flashing line cursor in an edit control ? Maybe change it's color or change it entirely ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can assign a Bitmap for example. See [CreateCaret](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information. With [ShowCaret](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can make it visible for a specified window. But please take a look at the `Remarks` section of the msdn article.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems a bit confusing, but that's the way to go. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can process the `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` message.

MSDN says "An edit control that is not read-only or disabled sends the WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message to its parent window when the control is about to be drawn. By responding to this message, the parent window can use the specified device context handle to set the text and background colors of the edit control".

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking to change the blinking/flashing line, I think its called Caret.